# RedirectCond Help for subdomains for www and www2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We have 2 subdomains `www.mydomain.com` and `www2.mydomain.com`. I'm trying to redirect pages to new site as below:

- `www.mydomain.com/support to newdomain.com/site1/page1.html`
- `www2.mydomain.com/support to newdomain.com/site2/page2.html`

I've set the redirect rule in `httpd.conf` as below:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?mydomain.com
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
>
> RewriteRule ^/support/?$ http://newdomain.com/site1/page1.html [R=301,NC,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www2.)?mydomain.com
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
>
> RewriteRule ^/support/?$ http://newdomain.com/site2/page2.html [R=301,NC,L]

The first redirect rule is working fine, but not the other. In above case, both `www` and `www2.mydomain.com/support` are going to `newdomain.com/site1/page1.html`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, anti-slashed point is a true point match, I've tested in apache2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/support/?$ http://mydomain.com/site1/page1.html [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www2\.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/support/?$ http://mydomain.com/site2/page2.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

We use www. instead of (www.)?.

Comment: Thanks jacouh. I added the \, but still the 2nd redirect rules are not working.

Comment: Let's add ^ starting anchor before www?

Answer (score 0):

try to check boths www and www2 in the same condition

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com|www2\.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/support/?$ http://example.com/site1/page1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```